# Can I choose security group names for non-default VPC in a CloudFormation template console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to able to choose from list of securitygroup names for a non-default VPC in an account. The below code shows list of security group names but it does not create a stack since it is looking for securitygroup id. How can I get security group id if I enter securitygroup name from console using `allowedvalues`?

```
 "VpcId":{
            "Description":"Choose the VPC ID"
            "Type":"AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },
"SecurityGroupsID":{
            "Description": "Choose availablity zone Availability Zone of the Subnet",
            "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::GroupName"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want the user to choose from a **list of names**, but then have the value accessible within the template as the **Security Group ID** (rather than Name).

This is **not possible**, since they are two totally different values.

If you wish to write some code, you could write a [CloudFormation Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) using AWS Lambda. The function could take the name as an input, then lookup the security group. It could then return the Security Group ID, which could be referenced elsewhere in the template.